# adding a paypal ipn redirect when selecting paypal on my websites drop down options

Tags: php

php newbie here. I am looking to integrate a paypal ipn redirect upon the user selecting paypal from the drop down options on my processing.php page, any help will be much appreciated as struggling abit and trying to learn more about this process, if anybody could walk me through this that would be great! many thanks

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Processing extends CI_Controller
{


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        if ($this->session->userdata("userID") == "") {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("processloginredirect", 1);

            redirect(base_url());
            exit;
        }


    }


    public function index()
    {
        $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

        $charactersLength = strlen($characters);

        $randomString = '';

        for ($i = 0; $i < 14; $i++) {

            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];

        }
        $this->session->set_userdata("assigntransactionID", $randomString);


        $data['allcurrency'] = $this->db->query("select * from allcurrency where isactive = 1")->result_array();


        $data['allsendingcurrency'] = $this->db->query("select *,c.id as currencyID from allcurrency as c inner join sending_accounts as sa on (c.id = sa.currencyID) where c.isactive = 1 order by sa.ordernumber")->result_array();

        $data['allreceivecurrency'] = $this->db->query("select *,c.id as currencyID from allcurrency as c inner join receive_accounts as ra on (c.id = ra.currencyID) where c.isactive = 1 order by ra.ordernumber")->result_array();


        if ($this->session->userdata("youhave_currency")) {

            $youget_currency_data = $this->db->query("select * from allcurrency where id = " . $this->session->userdata("youget_currency") . "")->row_array();

            $youhave_currency_data = $this->db->query("select * from allcurrency where id = " . $this->session->userdata("youhave_currency") . "")->row_array();


            $site_config = $this->db->query("select * from site_config")->row_array();


            $data['userwalletinfo'] = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM allcurrency AS c INNER JOIN players_wallet AS pw ON (c.id = pw.currencyID) WHERE 
     pw.playerID = " . $this->session->userdata("userID") . " AND c.symbol = '" . $youhave_currency_data['symbol'] . "'")->row_array();

            $admin_account_detail = $this->db->query("select * from allcurrency as c inner join receive_accounts as ac on (c.id = ac.currencyID) where c.id = '" . $youhave_currency_data['id'] . "'")->row_array();


            if ($admin_account_detail['iscryptocurrency'] == 0) {


                $accountinfo = '';
                $accountforcopy = '';
                if ($admin_account_detail['accountemail'] || $admin_account_detail['accountwalletkey']) {
                    if ($admin_account_detail['accountwalletkey']) {
                        $accountinfo .= "Account Address : " . $admin_account_detail['accountwalletkey'];
                        $accountforcopy = $admin_account_detail['accountwalletkey'];
                    } else {
                        $accountinfo .= "Account Address : " . $admin_account_detail['accountemail'];
                        $accountforcopy = $admin_account_detail['accountemail'];
                    }
                }
                if ($admin_account_detail['mobilenumber']) {
                    $accountinfo .= "<br>Mobile Number : " . $admin_account_detail['mobilenumber'];
                }
                if ($admin_account_detail['idcardnumber']) {
                    $accountinfo .= "<br>ID Card Number : " . $admin_account_detail['idcardnumber'];
                }


                $adminwallet_data = $accountinfo;


            } else {
                $adminwallet_data = $admin_account_detail['accountwalletkey'];
            }


            $data['adminwallet'] = $adminwallet_data;//$admin_account_detail['symbol_title']." Address : ".$admin_account_detail['accountwalletkey'];    
            $data['adminwallet_forcopy'] = $accountforcopy;

            $data['sendcurrencynumber_step4'] = $this->session->userdata("youhave") . ' ' . $youhave_currency_data['symbol_title'];


        } else {
            $data['userwalletinfo'] = array();
            $data['adminwallet'] = '';
            $data['sendcurrencynumber_step4'] = '';

        }


        if ($this->session->userdata("youhave_currency")) {
            $data['youhave'] = $this->session->userdata("youhave");
            $data['youhave_currency'] = $this->session->userdata("youhave_currency");
            $data['youget_currency'] = $this->session->userdata("youget_currency");
            $data['youget'] = number_format($this->session->userdata("youget"), 10);
        } else {

            $json = file_get_contents("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=ETH");
            $asdasdasdsa = json_decode($json);

            $get_currency_amount = $asdasdasdsa->ETH * 1;

            $depositefee_chrge = $site_config['depositefee'] * $get_currency_amount / 100;

            $get_currency_amount = $get_currency_amount - $depositefee_chrge;

            $this->session->set_userdata("youhave", 1);
            $this->session->set_userdata("youhave_currency", 1);
            $this->session->set_userdata("youget", number_format($get_currency_amount, 10));
            $this->session->set_userdata("youget_currency", 2);

            $data['youhave'] = $this->session->userdata("youhave");
            $data['youhave_currency'] = $this->session->userdata("youhave_currency");
            $data['youget_currency'] = $this->session->userdata("youget_currency");
            $data['youget'] = $this->session->userdata("youget");


            $admin_account_detail = $this->db->query("select * from allcurrency as c inner join receive_accounts as ac on (c.id = ac.currencyID) where c.symbol = 'BTC'")->row_array();

            $data['adminwallet'] = $admin_account_detail['symbol_title'] . " Address : " . $admin_account_detail['accountwalletkey'];     //$admin_account_detail['accountwalletkey'];   

            $data['sendcurrencynumber_step4'] = $this->session->userdata("youhave") . ' ' . $admin_account_detail['symbol_title'];
```

Comment: what is a "paypal ipn redirect " ?

Comment: upon the user selecting paypal from the ''you have'' drop down menu, it redirects them to pay with paypal. thanks

Comment: ok, that's nothing to do with paypals IPN, hence my confusion

Comment: sorry about that! any help much appreciated

Comment: Removed comments from code, better indentation

Comment: Any help with this guys? cheers